# Is it possible to execute cucumber scenario's in parallel on different browsers(chrome and firefox) at same time?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm, testng-dataprovider

I succeeded to run cucumber scenario's in parallel but only on one browsertype(chrome or firefox). So first I run my tests on chrome. When tests finish I start a second test run on firefox.

Is it possible to run cucumber scenarios in parallel on different browsertypes at same time?

See cucumber bdd documentation how to achieve parallel execution of scenarios at https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/

I use testNG as testrunner!

Thanks a lot for your responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a your tests against a matrix of browsers. Typically this matrix configured in CI and provided to the test execution via environment variables. For example using [Gitlab CI Matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel-matrix-jobs):

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn test
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - OS: Windows
        OS_VERSION: 10
        BROWSER: [Chrome, Firefox, Edge]
      - OS: OS X
        OS_VERSION: Big Sur
        BROWSER: [Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari]
```

You then create the web driver in the before hook using the environment variables.

```java
    @Before
    public void before(Scenario scenario){
        String os = System.getenv("OS");
        String osVersion = System.getenv("OS_VERSION");
        String browser = System.getenv("BROWSER");
        driver = createDriver(os, osVersion, browser);
    }
```

You could also use Maven Profiles or Gradle Tasks to define these different sets of environment variables.

However key is to let these jobs in parallel on your CI system by starting multiple JVMs rather then only in Cucumber by starting multiple threads.

Comment: @Korstanje thanks for the new insights. I agree, this is the solution. I will try to implement  you solution. I don't use cucumber hooks but instead testNG and guice dependency injection. Dependent on the type of testing I will do(web or mobile) the dependent Class is injected. What is the purpose of before(Scenario scenario)?

Comment: It sets up the webdriver before the scenario runs. You can also do that when creating the driver in DI. It is the simplest example, but may not be the example you need.

Comment: I implemeted this but not achieved what I want. My goal is to run all cucumber scenario's in parallel. For example if I have 4 scenario's and I want to test them on chrome and firefox then in total 8 (4 chrome + 4 firefox) browser instances are created in parallel. Now 2 browser instances are created in parallel(1 chrome + 1 firefox). And the 4 scenario's are tested in sequence and not parellel.

Comment: Sounds like your individual test runs are no running scenarios in parallel. You may want to ask a new question. Make sure you make your problem small enough to fit into a question, and at the same time detailed enough to cover your problem.

Comment: And I should have said, you run a suite for each browser in parallel by having multiple jobs in CI and then you run the scenarios in each suite in parallel the regular way.

Answer (score 0):

See the following answer [Is it posible to run feature cucumber in parallel in different browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684416/is-it-posible-to-run-feature-cucumber-in-parallel-in-different-browser)

This link at https://github.com/prashant-ramcharan/courgette-jvm-selenium explains how to achieve by using courgette-jvm(extension on cucumber-jvm).