# Is there a way to execute a suite of tests on multiples applications without unistalling and reinstalling the app very single time? using cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, spring-boot-test, gherkin

Good morning everyone,

I have a huge question about cucumber framework.

This is my situation right now :

I have 4 applications using the white label approach (4 apps are similar). Remember that in every app, we have to log in first. Let's say for example, I've created a .feature file for each feature.

Could I launch all the tests in a specific application? Once those tests are finished, rerun the same test suite in the next app. We do the same flow until we have tested all apps.

The actual behaviour that I have right now is :

I have my feature file.

```
Feature: page 1

 @page1.  
 Scenario: The page 1 contains an element 1

   Given the app1 is installed on a mobile device
   When the user launch the app1
   Then the user login with his account

 @page1.  
 Scenario: The page 1 contains an element 2

   Given the app1 is installed on a mobile device
   When the user launch the app1
   Then the user login with his account
```

Keep in mind that :

- the element will change depending on what account he is log in.
- I want to test the same flow on 3 different applications (same interface, different logos)

When I run a specific feature file, the way that it executes the test are :

Test the first scenario on the first application, then uninstall it

Test the same scenario with the other application, then uninstall it

Same flow until we have tested all apps.

Then, do the same flow with the next scenario.

What I'm trying to do is to find a way that I can say :

Ok we are going to install the first app, and run all the test that we have to tests on,
once we have finished testing the first app, we do the same with the next one.

IMPORTANT... it is possible that in a feature file, I'll need to test the same scenario with several accounts (that's why I have to use a scenario outline with that). Still, I could use the same data to test other scenarios but I want to avoid installing and uninstalling the app every time we are executing some tests.

Do you have already faced this kind of issue?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Have a look at this answer. It's about testing different webbrowsers, not apps, but you could as a first step install the app in a before all hook instead of open a browser in a before hook. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72215384/is-it-possible-to-execute-cucumber-scenarios-in-parallel-on-different-browsers/72223094#72223094

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber and other BDD frameworks are really great at helping people discuss the behaviour of an application and agree on how it should behave in different contexts, using a semi-formal language (Gherkin). I think of it as a specification tool which produces tests as a byproduct.

What you're talking about is testing behaviour in multiple different application contexts. Cucumber isn't really designed for working across those multiples, let alone for installing applications to multiple environments. For that, you probably want to look at your build tools (Jenkins, for example).

If you can get the suite to run in whatever application context it is presented with, you can make the build deploy those contexts and run the suite for each of them.

Your build tool can run any scripts which set up accounts, migrate data and install and configure apps. There are lots of DevOps tools and simulated environments which can help to manage those contexts too.

While it might be *possible* to do it in Cucumber by overriding the scenario runner, it isn't really something that Cucumber is designed to do.