# How to Run Cucumber TesNG in multibrowser with Parallel

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

Hook:

@Before(chrome)
{initiate Chrome}

@before(firefox)
{initiate ff}

Feature:
@chrome @firefox
Scenario 1 {Given, When Then}

Actual result:
Chrome and FF browser trigger at same time but test run on ff and nothing happens on Chrome

TestRunner:
CucumberOptions:
extends AbbstractTestNG --> Returns super.scenarios.

Options Tried:

1. Used Tags in Runner ex: Chrome --> In this case, all tests run on Chrome browser but also firefox opens whererever both tags are mentioned.
2. I need to copy same scenario multiple times with different browser tag then it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to execute cucumber scenario's in parallel on different browsers(chrome and firefox) at same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72215384/is-it-possible-to-execute-cucumber-scenarios-in-parallel-on-different-browsers)

Comment: No. Not able to get the solution. As of now, I can do parallel execution in one browser at a time. To achieve what I want, I have created duplicate feature files and used tags as chrome / ff etc. But this is wrong because I am creating duplicate features with different tags (for browsers). Any solution @M