Execute cucumber feature file parallel
How to execute cucumber feature file parallel.
I have created a own TestRunner by extending the org.junit.runners.ParentRunner, which is able to run the cucumber tests sequentially after launching the Chrome browser, but due to 5000 tests are there, so it took 4 days to complete all.
What are the steps to run many tests parallelly or it's not possible ?

See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#parallel-execution and to get started use https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

@M.P.Korstanje
Can different tests be run on different web browsers parallelly ?

For some definition of parallel, with some effort https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72215384/is-it-possible-to-execute-cucumber-scenarios-in-parallel-on-different-browsers/72223094#72223094
